# Leave Space ignoring character/spaces

Tags: sql-server, space, content-length

I have a task of selecting some columns and show each set of columns in a single line, but with a required format. The first set of data will use 127 spaces, which include 'AAAA', [LV_WRR], 'D', [LV_WRR] and [ID], but [ID] varies in length, and that is the problem.
[FTA] should start in the space 128, disregarding the length used by [ID].

This is what I have up to now:

```
SELECT
    'AAAA'
  + [LV_WRR]
  + 'D'
  + [LV_WRR]
  + [ID]
  + SPACE(120 - LEN([ID]))
  + [FTA]
  + [FT_ID]
FROM MyTable
```

[ID] column has the data with different lengths.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
LEFT('AAAA' + [LV_WRR] + 'D' + [LV_WRR] + [ID] + REPLICATE(' ',127),127)  + [FTA] + [FT_ID]
FROM MyTable
```

`REPLICATE` creates a 127 character long string of spaces. This is appended to the string formed by the other column values and constants. `LEFT` then takes the 127 leftmost characters of this string, and appends values from `[FTA]` and `[FT_ID]` columns. The result is that the value for `FTA` always starts at position 128.

A sample demo can be found [here](http://rextester.com/QHGOW53825).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get a different result in SQL Server 2008. 'pqrs' are not aligned.

Comment: I tried on SQL Server 2008 R2 and they are aligned as per demo. Could you help to set up a SQLFiddle with some sample data, so I can reproduce the result please?